# JS: Using Length Property to Write If Statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm very new to JS so go easy on me. I've got this array inside a variable, and am trying to find a better way to write that if statement. So if the names inside that variable grow, I won't need to change the if statement as it won't be hardcoded.

```
var names = ["beth", "barry", "debbie", "peter"]

if (names[0] && names [1] && names [2] && names [3] {
    Do something...
}
```

Something tells me I need to be using the `.length` property but I can't work out how to properly use it within that statement. Something along the lines of:

```
if (names[i] * names.length) { 
    Do something...
}
```

I know that's wrong. I think need to be finding the index of each and looping through it makign sure it the loop doesn't exceed the amount of values in the array.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Update:** Some users have alerted me that my question might not be as clear. I've setup a CodePen here (http://codepen.io/realph/pen/KjCLd?editors=101) that might explain what I'm trying to achieve.

P.S. How do I stop my from repeating 3 times?

Comment: What's your purpose with the code? because i'm not able to understand what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: Your if statement as written says, if 1st through 4th elements of the names array are not false, undefined or null, then do stuff. What is it the if statement should be saying?

Comment: `["beth", "barry", "debbie", "peter"].reduce(function(a,b){return a && b!==undefined;},true)` - return `true` if all items not _undefined_

Comment: @Grundy `every` would be the better option

Comment: @meagar yep, i don't known about _every_ :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to test whether every element satisfies some condition:

```
if (names.every(function (name) { return name })) {
  // Do Something
}
```

`every` will automatically stop testing when the first non-true element is found, which is potentially a large optimization depending on the size of your array.

Traditionally, you would simply iterate over the array and test each element. You can do so with [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or a simple `for` loop. You can perform the same early-termination when you find a non-true element by returning `false` from the `forEach` callback.

```
var allTrue = true;

names.forEach(function (name) {
  return allTrue = allTrue && name;
});

if (allTrue) { 
  // Do something...
}
```

Comment: Note that `forEach` doesn't work in IE8 and lower. -- http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/

Comment: +1 But the `forEach` and `every` method are not similar because the later can short-circuit

Comment: @thefourtheye The linked page in the answer has a polyfill for `every`, not `forEach`

Comment: The only way to do this in pure javascript with no worries of cross-browser compatibility is to use a simple `for` loop. There's no need to complicate this by requiring polyfills

Comment: @meager this is a very simple scenario that the op asked for a javascript solution to with no other assumptions. If you are using this kind of logic everywhere in a large app then yes it's worth adding a polyfill, but in this case it just complicates what is already only a couple lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for this @meagar, I'm going to give this a shot and read up on `every`! A few users pointed out that my question might not have read as clear as I intended. I've added a CodePen to my original question with what I'm intending to do with the if statement.

Comment: @meagar not mentioning any requirements for browsers is the exact reason you need to mention that it doesn't work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

*Please give a english description of what you are trying to accomplish. The below answer assumes you simply want to iterate a list of names and do some processing with each.*

You want to use a [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop.

```
var names = ["beth", "barry", "debbie", "peter"]

for (var i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
    // access names[i]
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question. Hopefully that better explains what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The best cross-browser solution is to use a traditional for loop.

```
var names = ["beth", "barry", "debbie", "peter"],
    isValid = true,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    isValid = isValid && names[i];
}

if (isValid) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this;

```
    var checkCondition = true;
    for(var i = 0; i<names.length; i++){
      if(names[i] !== something) {
         checkCondition = false;
         break;
      } 
    }
    if(checkCondition){
        //Do what ever you like if the condition holds
    }else{
        // Do whatever you like if the condition does NOT holds
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand right you need something like this

```
var names = ["beth", "barry", "debbie", "peter"];
var notUndefinedNames = names.filter(function(el){return el !== undefined;});

// if all
if (names.length === notUndefinedNames.length) console.log("You're all here. Great! Sit down and let's begin the class.");

// if one or less
else if (notUndefinedNames.length <= 1) console.log("I can't teach just one person. Class is cancelled.");

else console.log("Welcome " + notUndefinedNames.join(', '));
```